# Need to control a serial port via .NET. What HW/SW choices to I have that run CLR 2.0?

Tags: c#, hardware, .net-micro-framework

I need to control 128 different serial lines via .NET (simply because I know it).  I hear there are various Basic Stamps available, and then some XP, CE, Micro, and Embedded options available to me.

/update:

My plan is to have a MUX of some type break down my serial line into a specific address.  I'm not planning on having 128 individual serial controllers.

/endupdate

I simply want to have a C# application control a serial port (as directed by an input file of some type) continuously in a loop.  If your interested, I'm ultimately controlling 128 solenoids that are either in an open or closed state.

What is the best HW//SW solution for this device?  If I have a serial output, I'm planning on having a multiplexer break out the commands to the correct device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here:
http://www.moxa.com/product/nport_6650.htm

Converts 32 serial ports to a TCP server with 32 TCP ports.
Connect to each COM port, via TcpClient or other suitable TCP client.

- Price works out to $51/COM port
- Robust and tidy solution.

Answer (score 0):

128 UARTs is a lot and I'd say the issue here is going to be cost.  I know of no hardware with anywhere near that - in fact hardware with a "lot" would be something like 8.  I know you're saying you want a .NET solution, but to be cost effective, I think a microsontroller is at least worth a look.

Personally I'd probably do a boatload of PICs - maybe on an I2C bus and have some master controller running CE.  That would definitely be my first investigation.  A quad-UART PIC is less that $5.

If a microcontroller solution isn't palatable to you (and I think it's really the only wise solution), then the only other thing I can think of (and this is an ugly kludge) would be a boatload of USB quad uarts on some ugly daisy chain of hubs.  I have no idea what the OS would do trying to load this many drivers - I've never seen it even attempted (and actually never even considered it).

Exactly why are you using serial for this anyway?  If the solenoid is eitehr open or closed, that sure sounds like a digital I/O would do - in that case I'd use a few PICs, again on I2C or SPI to drive them via digital outputs.

**EDIT**

Based on your update, then most any CE device will work.  I low-cost [eBox 3300 x86](http://www.wdlsystems.com/modperl/view_services.cgi?r=detail&prod_num=1EB33WE&aisle_id=1060) device has a pair.  That's going to be something like $260 in qty 1.  A ARM-based [beagle board](https://specialcomp.com/beagleboard/index.htm) has lower power consumption and is under $200, though it doesn't have the nice enclosure.

Comment: I just updated the question... I am mostly focused on a board with a single serial/parallel port.  Not looking for 128 UART's!  That is a lot of money.  The serial port could address the MUX, and then send the on/off bit.  I just need to know what .NET stamp will drive a serial port.  Anything else is gravy and allows for more features.

Comment: As far as the "exactly why" part: I'm using solenoids to control the flow of water in an Art project Im playing with.  If the Mux isn't the best idea, perhaps I could look at the I2C, but I'm not familliar with it at all